# Actor stats not being sent to StatsD from Kamon

Tags: akka-http, akka-monitoring, kamon

I'm trying to use [Kamon](http://kamon.io/introduction/get-started/) with [StatsD backend](https://github.com/kamon-io/docker-grafana-graphite) for Akka monitoring/telemetry. I currently only have one actor and I'm sending an `ask` which replies to the caller. I can see my custom counter data in Graphana and Graphite as well as JVM and OS stats, but no actor stats from Akka. My project is setup just like [this intro](https://github.com/lancearlaus/akka-streams-http-intro) but I have added the Kamon stuff and my own HttpService. What am I missing?

Here's my config:

```
kamon {
  trace.level = simple-trace
  metric {
    tick-interval = 1 second
    filters {
      akka-actor.includes = [ "**" ]
      akka-router.includes = [ "**" ]
      akka-dispatcher.includes = [ "**" ]
      trace.includes =  [ "**" ]
      trace-segment.includes =  [ "**" ]
      histogram.includes =  [ "**" ]
      min-max-counter.includes =  [ "**" ]
      gauge.includes =  [ "**" ]
      counters.includes =  [ "**" ]
      # For web projects
      http-server.includes = [ "**" ]

      akka-actor.excludes = [ "**" ]
      akka-router.excludes = [ "**" ]
      akka-dispatcher.excludes = [ "**" ]
      counters.excludes =  [ "" ]
      trace-segment.excludes =  [ "" ]
      histogram.excludes =  [ "" ]
      min-max-counter.excludes =  [ "" ]
      gauge.excludes =  [ "" ]
      http-server.excludes =  [ "" ]
    }
  }

  akka {
    ask-pattern-timeout-warning = "lightweight"
  }

  statsd {
    hostname = "localhost" //Graphite Host
    port = "8125"
    flush-interval = 1 second
    max-packet-size = 1024 bytes
    subscriptions {
      histogram = ["**"]
      min-max-counter = ["**"]
      gauge = ["**"]
      counter = ["**"]
      trace = ["**"]
      trace-segment = ["**"]
      system-metric = ["**"]
      akka-actor = ["**"]
      akka-dispatcher = ["**"]
      http-server = ["**"]
    }
    report-system-metrics = true

    simple-metric-key-generator {
      application = "data-id-generator"
    }
  }
  system-metrics {
    #sigar is enabled by default
    sigar-enabled = false

    #jmx related metrics are enabled by default
    jmx-enabled = true
  }
}
```

Here's my service:

```
import akka.event.Logging
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.{ByteString, Timeout}
import com.incontact.data.GeneratorActor.GenerateId
import com.incontact.data.IdGenerator.{GeneratorError, IdResult}
import com.incontact.http.HttpService
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes._
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport
import spray.json._
import kamon.Kamon

import scala.concurrent.duration._

trait IdService extends HttpService with SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {
  private lazy val log = Logging(system, classOf[IdService])

  implicit val timeout: Timeout = 1.second
  //implicit val errorFormat = jsonFormat2(GeneratorError)

  abstract override def route: Route = {
    log.info("creating generator actor")
    val generator = system.actorOf(GeneratorActor.props, "generator")
    val counter = Kamon.metrics.counter("generate-long-id")

    path("") {
      get {
        counter.increment()
        log.info("IdService sending single request to actor")
        onSuccess((generator ? GenerateId).mapTo[IdResult]) {
          case Right(id) => complete(ByteString(s"${id}\n"))
          case Left(e:GeneratorError) => failWith(e.Error)
        }
      }
    }
  } ~ super.route
}
```

Main.scala (startup)

```
import akka.event.Logging
import com.incontact.data.IdService
import com.incontact.http.HttpServer
import kamon.Kamon

import scala.io.StdIn
import scala.util.Success

object Main extends App
  with HttpServer
  with IdService {

  Kamon.start()

  private lazy val log = Logging(system, getClass)
  bindingFuture.andThen {
    case Success(binding) =>
      // this really doesn't support any production behavior since [ENTER] won't be used to shut down the docker container
      log.info("Press ENTER to exit")
      StdIn.readLine()
      log.info("Shutting down...")
      Kamon.shutdown()
      system.terminate()
  }
}
```

build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
val akkaVersion = "2.4.14"
val kamonVersion = "0.6.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 // remove multiple-dependency warnings
 "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value,
 "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.5",

 // application dependencies
 "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion,
 "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.0.0",
 "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % "10.0.0",
 "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-dynamodb" % "1.11.63",

 // kamon dependencies
 "io.kamon" %% "kamon-core" % kamonVersion,
 "io.kamon" %% "kamon-statsd" % kamonVersion,
 "io.kamon" %% "kamon-system-metrics" % kamonVersion,
 "org.aspectj" % "aspectjweaver" % "1.8.6",

 // test dependencies
 "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % akkaVersion % "test",
 "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % "test",
 "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-testkit" % "10.0.0" % "test",
 "org.pegdown" % "pegdown" % "1.1.0" % "test"
)
```

project/plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("io.kamon" % "aspectj-runner" % "0.1.3")
```

launch from command-line:

```
$ sbt aspectj-runner:run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're excluding all the actors/dispatcher/router metrics in your config. This should rule all metrics out (even if you're also including them all).

```
  akka-actor.excludes = [ "**" ]
  akka-router.excludes = [ "**" ]
  akka-dispatcher.excludes = [ "**" ]
```

Try and change it to

```
  akka-actor.excludes = [  ]
  akka-router.excludes = [  ]
  akka-dispatcher.excludes = [  ]
```

Comment: I guess more code might help. E.g. are you starting Kamon? are you importing the kamon-akka module? how are you setting up the weaving with AspectJ?

Comment: I didn't know about the kamon-akka module. I'll try adding that

Comment: adding the kamon-akka module fixed it. Thanks!